# WPF : Animating Width of an Control alternately with start value

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, triggers, storyboard

I have an image whose width should be animated from 0 to 30 pixels when a boolean property changes to `true` an back from 30 to 0 pixels if the property switches back to `false`. 
In general, this works with this XAML code:

```
    <Image.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">

        <!-- <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/> -->

        <Style.Triggers>                 
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=AIM, Path=IsDeletingEnabled}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>

            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
              <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                  <!-- Animate the Width of the Image from 0 to 30px within 300ms-->
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="0" To="30" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
              <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                  <!-- Animate the Width of the Image from 30 to 0px within 300ms-->
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="30" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>

          </DataTrigger>   
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </Image.Style>
  </Image>
```

The problem is, that before the Property `IsDeletingEnabled` switches to true the first time, the images witdh is 30px and it is visible. When I uncomment the first setter and set the `Witdh` to 0px by default (or the `Visibility`to `Hidden`), the image isn't shown at startup but disappears instantly after switching `IsDeletingEnabled` from `true`to `fals`. In this case, no animation is visible.

Has anywone a solution how I can set the `Visibility`to `Hidden`or the `Witdh`to 0px at startup without hiding the `DataTrigger.ExitAction` ?

Comment: What is `IsDeletingEnabled`? What is Element `AIM`? Some do not understand exactly how to work the animation. When do you have it running, and where not? I'm working fine show / hide the image with CheckBox (property `IsChecking`).

Comment: The Image is part of a UserControl, `IsDeletingEnabled` is a boolean `DependencyProperty` of this control that is set by the view model of the parent window, `AIM` is the name of the UserControl in XAML. I use `ElementName="AIM"` to avoid setting `DataContext`. At startup, `IsDeletingEnabled` is `false`. In this case, the `Image`shouldn't be visible. But when I use a setter for this, the Animation on `ExitAction` does not work.

Comment: As I understood, if you set `IsDeletingEnabled` true animation work, but if set false animation not work?

Comment: Without `<Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>` animation works for true and for false. But the Image is visible with full witdh after opening the window (`IsDeletingEnabled == false`) and disappers not until `IsDeletingEnabled` changes the first time from true to false. With the setter, the width is set to 0 immediately after `IsDeletingEnabled` changes from true to false.

Answer (score 0):

Do you explicitly need to set the `Visibility` to `Hidden` if you're setting the `Width` to 0? A zero-width element and a hidden element look the same onscreen.

Your exit action is not being 'hidden', what's happening is the `DataTrigger` is 'undoing' the `<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>` in addition to running the exit action. But since the visibility has immediate effect you don't see the exit action being run.

Your enter action needs to both `Visibility=Visible` and start the expanding animation.  Your exit action needs to perform the shrinking animation, *but wait to set `Visibility=Visible` until after it's complete*.  You can do this with an `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` animation:

```
<Image.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Image">

        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>

        <Style.Triggers>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsShown}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <!-- Animate the Width of the Image from 0 to 30px within 300ms-->
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="0" To="30" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                            <!-- Set the Image to Visible immediately -->
                           <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <!-- Animate the Width of the Image from 30 to 0px within 300ms-->
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="30" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                            <!-- After 300ms, hide the Image -->
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Hidden</Visibility>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>

            </DataTrigger>

        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Image.Style>
```